# I want files ran from main python file to run from their own directory

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, operating-system

Example:

I have my main file, main.py with this code:

```
import os
os.popen("start folder/subfile.py")
```

Then i have my other file, subfile.py with this code:

```
file = open("test.txt", "w")
file.close()
```

I want my subfile.py to create the test.txt file in its own folder, but it creates it in the main.py's folder.

So my question is, how do i make the subfile.py run from it own folder even though it's started from main.py

main.py folder : C:/users/user/Desktop

subfile.py folder: C:/users/user/Desktop/folder

Comment: What is the purpose of spawning a new process rather than importing your second py file as a module and calling its functions directly?

Comment: In general the working directory will not be the directory of main.py. It's whatever the parent process set as the working directory, and no properly written program should rely on the initial working directory to find any of its private resources, such as finding your subfile.py script. Also, don't use `os.popen`. There's no reason to run this command via the shell. Use `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Beceuase in the real code the subfile is located in another directory and temporarily deletes the folder with "main.py", and it cant delete itself as far as i know.

Comment: @Lojas why do you delete the folder with main.py?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Because in my real situation, the main.py is in the folder  and the subfile.py is outside of it, it was just easier to explain it like this.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you are creating a subprocess. You can run the code in `subfile.py` more easily with `import subfile` or `import subfoler.subfile` and then call the functions directly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice But the code in the subfile.py delete the folder with main.py in, and replaces it with another, so i cant run it from main.py because it cant delete itself.

Comment: I asked earlier what is the reason for deleting the folder with main.py and you still just repeat **what** you are doing without explaining **why**.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Seems like i misread your question then. It's deleting the folder because it's updating it with another one which is downloaded from a server as a .zip, and then unpacked as the replacer.

Comment: What is the purpose for doing this? Why is the zip file opened in the exact same directory as the `main.py` rather than in a different directory?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It's not opened in the same directory as main.py, it replaces the folder with main.py inside of i which means it opens outside of it. The purpose behind it is so i can update the program remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `subfile.py`, change the working directory ([`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir)) to the directory that contains the `subfile.py` **file**:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use subprocess instead which has that built in:

```
subprocess.Popen(sys.executable + ' subfile.py', cwd=os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/folder')
```

Comment: The main script could be run with any working directory. You absolutely must get the path of main.py via `__file__`. Also, what if the py.exe launcher isn't installed? It's safer to run this via `sys.executable`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
import os
import inspect

your_current_folder_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
your_current_file_path = os.path.join(your_current_folder_path, "test.txt")

print(your_current_folder_path)
print(your_current_file_path)


with open(your_current_file_path, "w") as make_file:
    make_file.write("")

print("Done.")
```

Another way: you can change your working directory by os.chdir("your_folder_directory") function.

```
os.chdir(r"C:/users/user/Desktop/folder")
```